# Wrong return value VBA function Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, return-value

I'm writing a VBA function which I need in my Excel spreadsheet, this is the code I wrote:

```vb
Function costo(x As Variant, d1 As Double, p1 As Double)
    Dim d As Variant
    d = Array(Array(129, 90), Array(129, 98), Array(142, 81), Array(133, 98), _
             Array(139, 102), Array(156, 144), Array(125, 127), Array(137, 222), _
             Array(213, 241), Array(145, 229), Array(206, 118), Array(152, 167))
    Dim c As Double
    c = 0
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 12
        c = c + 50 * x(i) * distanza(d1, p1, d(i)(0), d(i)(1))
    Next i
    costo = c
End Function


Function distanza(ByVal d1 As Double, ByVal p1 As Double, ByVal d2 As Double, ByVal p2 As Double) As Double
    Dim r As Double
    r = 6371
    distanza = 2 * r * WorksheetFunction.Asin(Sqr(WorksheetFunction.Power(Sin((d1 - d2) / 2), 2) + _
             Cos(d1) * Cos(d2) * WorksheetFunction.Power(Sin((p1 - p2) / 2), 2)))
End Function
```

`x` are 12 cells of my spreadsheet, while `d1` and `p1` are two cell.

When I run the code in debug, the variable `costo` have the correct value, but in my spreedsheet I get `#VALUE!`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `Debug.? lbound(d, 1), ubound(d, 1)`

Comment: Call `costo` from a Sub, then you can debug it.

Comment: Your costo function appears to be missing an `As value` declaration.

Comment: May be, error occurs in function ``costo``. Most likely pointed by @GSerg. In this case Excel not informs about error. Cell value become #VALUE!. Check errors with ``on error`` clause.

Comment: It's my first time using VBA, running in debug i see that the variable c change its value in every iteration of the for loop, but when at the end the script has to return costo which is equal to c, i get #VALUE!

Comment: Your vba code is debuggered OK. It's floating overflow ?

Comment: I believe the For Loop should be 0 to 11.  And depending on how `X` is defined maybe it is referenced by `x(i+1)` or remains by `x(i)`

Comment: Declare your return type: Function costo(x As Variant, d1 As Double, p1 As Double) AS DOUBLE  Also make sure  the variable that is receiving the return value is declared as double.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add error handler on error go to, exit function and messagebox. I got same #VALUE but i dunno what numbers you adding. My error says subcript out of range. Numbers too high.

```
Function costo(x As Variant, d1 As Double, p1 As Double)
    On Error GoTo MY_ERROR
    Dim d As Variant
    d = Array(Array(129, 90), Array(129, 98), Array(142, 81), Array(133, 98), _
             Array(139, 102), Array(156, 144), Array(125, 127), Array(137, 222), _
             Array(213, 241), Array(145, 229), Array(206, 118), Array(152, 167))
    Dim c As Double
    c = 0
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 12
        c = c + 50 * x(i) * distanza(d1, p1, d(i)(0), d(i)(1))
    Next i
    costo = c
    Exit Function
    
MY_ERROR:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code causing the premature exit occurs because `d` is a 12-element variant array with `Lbound = 0` and `Ubound = 11`. So when you refer to the array elements in your `c=` line, when `i` reaches `12` you will have an out-of-bounds subscript error.

Change that line to:

```
c = c + 50 * x(i) * distanza(d1, p1, d(i - 1)(0), d(i - 1)(1))
```

and your code should run.